# Change selected value of dropdown-checklist with jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui

Can anyone explain me how I can set select item in a **dropdown-checklist**

For instance, dropdown-checklist I want dynamically select items. (i don't want delete or destroy the dropdown-checklist and rebuild again with news selected itms, for instnace).

P.S: The dropdown checklist can be visted here:

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/demo.html

Answer (score 4):

1. Select the desired option in the original select
2. Refresh the dropdownchecklist.

To select all options:

```
$("#myselect").find("option").attr("selected", "selected");
$("#myselect").dropdownchecklist("refresh");
```